# ASP.NET Core MVC. Как реализовать систему диалогов?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

Имеется приложение ASP.NET Core MVC в связке с MS SQL Server. Стоит задача реализовать систему диалогов (сообщений) между пользователями, наподобие как в любом мессенджере (Telegram, Skype, ВКонтакте и т.д.). То есть чтобы история сообщений сохранялась в БД и диалог можно было продолжить.

Подскажите, кто сталкивался с подобной задачей как решали. Какие подводные камни, может что почитать. Пока что на ум приходит поверх SignalR писать свою инфраструктуру.

Answer (score 1):

Использовали SignalR, очень удобен и разработка заняла не так много времени. Если количество сообщений будет очень большим, то можно задуматься о брокерах сообщений(RabbitMQ).
Основную сложность в создании чата заняла его архитектура, но это из-за особенностей создаваемой системы, если у вас все открыто, то будет проще.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. То есть грубо говоря вся история хранится в бд и на клиенте через SignalR синхронизируется? Про брокеры пока рано говорить. Нужны ли еще другие технологии\инструменты или все в пределах .net?

Comment: Да, у нас так. SignalR обладает довольно хорошим функционалом(не судите строго, "хороший" понятие субъективное). Но всякие широковещательные запросы он дает возможность делать.  По инструментам не скажу, потому что очень зависит от ситуации (нужно передавать файлы или нет, микросервисы или монолит). Исходите из задач и инфраструктуры. Но если все открыто и простая архитектура без ограничений, нужен простой чат без "уникальностей", то должно хватить.